# Unload a delay loaded dll in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, delay-load

I am trying to use __FUnloadDelayLoadedDLL2 with opengl32.dll.

I have already defined:

```
delayimp.lib /DELAYLOAD:OPENGL32.dll /DELAY:UNLOAD
```

in the linker options, and then

```
__FUnloadDelayLoadedDLL2("OPENGL32.dll")
```

but this returns false.

The name in the `__FUnloadDelayLoadedDLL2` must match exactly so I got it from the `DEPENDENTS table`.

If I call the `__FUnloadDelayLoadedDLL2("OPENGL32.dll")` again in a different point
in the code, it returns true which means that the dll is unloaded. BUT then I call `GetModuleHandle("OPENGL32.dll")` and the handle exists. Any idea?

Is it possible to unload the delay loaded `opengl32.dll`?
Or are there any conflicts with `gdi32.dll`?

Comment: Is the only thing, in your library dependency tree, that depends on `opengl32.dll`, is your application? Maybe there are other libraries, that are loaded, that depends on said library being loaded, and your unload DLL call merely reduced the refcount, of it.